# How do I convert 3tm to lat-lon

Tags: convert

I'm unable to find out a formula for converting 3tm coordinates to lat-lon?  3tm is a system used in Alberta alone, as far as I can tell.  The city of Calgary uses that for its opendata, which is what I'm trying to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gdaltransform will work, I must've just missed you on irc.  I assume that 3tm is the projection here:

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3776/

to convert to WGS84 longitude/latitude:

gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:3776 -t_srs epsg:4326

Then type in your coordinates.